# Using gsub for a specific occurrence in a string in R?

Tags: r, gsub

I have two strings:

```
mystring1 <- c("hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a cat.  dogs are the best animal.  not cats!")

mystring2 <- c("hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a cat.  but i have a cat friend that is a cat.")
```

I want to change the third occurrence of the word cat in both strings to dog.

Ideally, `string1` and `string2` would read:

```
mystring1
[1] "hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a dog.  dogs are the best animal.  not cats!"

mystring2
[1] "hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a dog.  but i have a cat friend that is a cat."
```

What is the best way of doing this?  Up until now I have only used `gsub` to replace characters but I don't know if this can be used to replace specific occurrences of a character.

Comment: Try `sub("(.*?cat.*cat.*)cat", "\\1dog", mystring1)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```r
mystring1 <- c("hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a cat.  dogs are the best animal.  not cats!")
mystring2 <- c("hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a cat.  but i have a cat friend that is a cat who knows a cat knowing a cat.")

sub("((cat.*?){2})\\bcat\\b", "\\1dog", mystring1, perl=TRUE)
```

which gives

```r
> sub("((cat.*?){2})\\bcat\\b", "\\1dog", c(mystring1, mystring2), perl=TRUE)
[1] "hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a dog.  dogs are the best animal.  not cats!"                                
[2] "hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a dog.  but i have a cat friend that is a cat who knows a cat knowing a cat."
```

Comment: It might be good to surround the `cat` with `\\b`'s

Comment: Why not use `sub("((cat.*?){2})cat", "\\1dog", c(mystring1, mystring2), perl=T)`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Good point, but OP didn't request doing both strings in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
p <- proto(fun = function(this, x) if(count == 3) 'dog' else x)
gsubfn('cat', p, c(mystring1, mystring2))

# [1] "hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a dog.  dogs are the best animal.  not cats!"  
# [2] "hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a dog.  but i have a cat friend that is a cat."
```

Or, if it needs to be surrounded by word boundaries,

```
gsubfn('\\bcat\\b', p, c(mystring1, mystring2), perl = TRUE)

# [1] "hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a dog.  dogs are the best animal.  not cats!"  
# [2] "hello i am a cat.  just kidding, i'm not a cat i'm a dog.  but i have a cat friend that is a cat."
```